# Redundant instantiations in boolean constant expressions

Tags: c++, c++11, instantiation, template-meta-programming, constant-expression

I have an n-any boolean `OR` run-time function `any_run`

```
#include <assert.h>

bool any_run() { return false; }

template <typename... B>
bool any_run(bool a, B... b)
{
    assert(a);
    return a || any_run(b...);
}
```

as well as a compile-time analogue `any_comp`

```
#include <type_traits>

template <bool E>
using expr = std::integral_constant <bool, E>;

using _true  = expr <true>;
using _false = expr <false>;

template <typename... A>
struct any_comp : public _false { };

template <typename A, typename... B>
struct any_comp <A, B...> : public expr <A() || any_comp <B...>()>
{
    static_assert(A(), "");
};
```

both of which contain assertions (run-time or compile-time, respectively) to ensure that the the first argument is true.

Now giving the following input

```
int main()
{
    any_run   (true,  false,  false);
    any_comp <_true, _false, _false>();
}
```

the run-time assertion never fails, but the compile-time one does. This means that `any_run(false, false)` is never called, however `any_comp <_false, _false>` does get instantiated, despite the fact that boolean constant expression

```
A() || any_comp <B...>()
```

could be evaluated to `true` if `A() == true` without ever instantiating `any_comp <B...>`.

**My question** is whether this experiment and its conclusion are valid, and what the standard would say about it.

It is important because if the conclusion is valid, I'd have to re-implement several compile-time functions more carefully (with more specializations) to make compilation faster, although I generally prefer to keep things as simple as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short-circuit only works on the run-time level for `||`. At compile-time, you need something else like:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename U>
struct integral_or : U { };

template <typename U>
struct integral_or <std::true_type, U> : std::true_type { };

template <typename... A>
struct any_comp : std::false_type { };

template <typename A, typename... B>
struct any_comp <A, B...> : integral_or <A, any_comp <B...>>
{
    static_assert(A(), "");
};

int main()
{
    any_comp <std::true_type, std::false_type, std::false_type>();
}
```

Comment: Right... and we're (almost) back to C++03... And I was so happy to throw away all those functions like `integral_and` that make everything so unreadable when more complex expressions occur. Thanks!

Comment: You could also overload the boolean operators to implement expression templates and provide a clearer syntax ( `decltype( a() || b() && c() )` for example. Like [this](https://github.com/Manu343726/Turbo/blob/master/expressions.hpp)